# Prononciation usuelle du nom propre « Jeanneney » ?

Tags: prononciation, noms-propres

Y a-t-il une manière plus usuelle qu'une autre de prononcer le nom (Jean-Noël) *Jeanneney* ? Le cas échéant est-ce deux ou trois syllabes, Jean (\ʒɑ̃\) ou Jeanne (\ʒan\) ou (\ʒa.nə\)... (\ne\), le *e* final dans Jeanne est-il « réduit », est-ce utile d'identifier le nom le plus court/long (Jean/Jeanne) dans le nom pour fins de prononciation (\ʒɑ̃.nə.ne\) ? Peut-on présenter son choix en API correct ainsi que par comparaison avec des mots dont les phonèmes sont bien connus/clairs ?

Comment: Il n'y a pas vraiment de règle précise pour les noms propres. Dans quel contexte se trouve ce mot ?

Answer (score 2):

Je prononcerais [ʒanənɛ] (ja-ne-nai) si je faisais un effort normal de prononciation ou bien [ʒannɛ] (ja-n-nai, avec un n allongé sans prononcer le [ə] du milieu) dans un registre informel. Dans les deux cas avec des liaisons, sans pause. Mais pour la prononciation des noms propres il n'y a pas vraiment de règle, c'est l'usage qui compte. Il serait par exemple tout à fait possible de prononcer la fin [e] au lieu de [ɛ] ou le début [ʒɑ̃], ce n'est simplement pas la prononciation à laquelle je m'attendais personnellement.

Answer (score 2):

La prononciation habituelle de ce nom est simplement équivalente à celle de "Jeanne Ney", où le e final de Jeanne est muet, soit [ʒannɛ] ou [ʒanne] suivant le locuteur.

On peut l'entendre au tout début de cette [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pfW55xG1K0) ou cette autre [ici](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1uk7c).